# Mirth Connect: javascript to call a webservice

Tags: javascript, web-services, axis, mirth

I'm trying to call a web service from a Mirth Channel transformer javascript using apache axis library (which it's supposed to be deployed with Mirth).
I've tried using the following java script, but it does not work:

```
/*importPackage(java.net);
importPackage(org.apache.axis.client.Call);
importPackage(org.apache.axis.client.Service);
importPackage(javax.xml.namespace.QName);*/

  var endpoint = 'http://tempuri.org/IService1/';
  var service = org.apache.axis.client.Service();
  var call = service.createCall();
  call.setTargetEndpointAddress( new URL(endpoint) );
  call.setOperationName(new QName('http://soapinterop.org/', 'SayHello'));
  var ret = call.invoke('John Doe');
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer:

- Auto-generate service client proxy with Axis WDSL2Jave tool
- Build a JAR archive with the auto-generated classes
- Copy the JAR file in %MirthInstallPath%/lib/custom
- Re-start Mirth service
- Create a transformer JavaScript with the following code (in this example the WS is called Service1, a sample WS coded with .NET):

> ```
> var locator = new Service1Locator();
> var wsdlURL = new URL('http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/HelloWorldWS/Service1'));
> var proxy = locator.getBasicHttpBinding_IService1(wsdlURL);
> var result = proxy.sayHello("John Doe");
> // use result to whatever message mapping you need to perform
> ```

That's all.