# Call a webservice from javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services

I would like to call a webservice from javascript.

I tried:

```
var locator = new Service1Locator();
var wsdlURL = new URL(address);
var proxy = locator.getBasicHttpBinding_IService1(wsdlURL);
var result = proxy.execute("John Doe");
```

taken from : [Mirth Connect: javascript to call a webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147983/mirth-connect-javascript-to-call-a-webservice) but it neither works nor do I understand it.

Can anyone help me please?

Lily

Comment: That particular question relies on using the Mirth javascript library.  Are you also using the same library or do you just want to call a web-service the easiest way you can?

Comment: just the easiest way possible

Comment: Is the web-service in the same domain as your application or are you trying to call an external web-service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call a web-service in the easiest way possible, it probably won't get much easier than using the [jQuery ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).  The documentation has some excellent examples (most are 1 to 3 lines of javascript).  You just need to make sure to include the jQuery library in the page header and all that fun stuff.